# Is there any local notification in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk, android-manifest, localnotification

In my application I want to use the Local Notification.
I don't know is there any local notification available in Android or not.

If yes then please give me any sample example to implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android doesn't really have a distinction between remote (push in Apple terms) and local notifications. You don't get a box pop up or any UI at all for free with Android's C2DM.

I think you just want to look at:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

For doing something at a certain time you want to look at:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Ok Thanks for the Answer. Let me check it.

Comment: I want the notification like that if i have set the notofication in to the application for perticular time and date then the device should display the message at that time even if the application is close. The message should be of any form or like the dialog. Is it possible?

Comment: For the "at a certain time" stuff, look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 1):

there is a sample of new Notification with PendingIntent for call Activity when the user click on.

[PendingIntent of Notification don't call my Activity second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320428/pendingintent-of-notification-dont-call-my-activity-second-time)

Answer (score 0):

yes, there are local notifications in android. To understand how to work with them see this answer - [How schedule local notifications Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106006/how-schedule-local-notifications-android/31946656#31946656)