# How schedule local notifications Android?

Tags: android, datetime, notifications, localnotification

I have a question about local notifications in Android. I am developing an application where in the first part I must receive all meetings of the company of my own server (this I have achieved), and the second part I must notify one day before each meeting, but with local notifications.

How to schedule local notifications at a given date?

Comment: Check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461191/alarmmanager-fires-alarms-at-wrong-time/21461246#21461246) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Answer (score 16):

To schedule local notification you need to know some of the things which are used to schedule the notification like:

1. `BroadcastReceiver`*s*
2. `IntentFilter`*s*
3. `AlarmManager`
4. `NotificationService`
5. `PendingIntent`

In the `MainActivity` do the following:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
 
        PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 15);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
    }
```

The above code will schedule an alarm after 15 seconds. After 15 seconds it will broadcast the `NotificationIntent`.

The action specified in the Intent constructor is defined in the **AndroidManifest.xml**

To understand the full working of local notification and to see a sample notification code check out [this article](http://www.singhajit.com/schedule-local-notification-in-android/)

Comment: what to do to repeat the process?

Comment: Use the HOUR_OF_DAY for Calendar and setRepeatingAlarm

`Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 09);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , broadcast);`

Comment: @Saty : could you accept this as answer if this helped solve your problem, otherwise put a comment that it didn't help. It would help others looking for similar question.

Comment: @AjitSingh Not calling the broadcast receiver at all in my app. Tried both app is closed & running conditions

Comment: NOTE: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#android_80 since android 8, don't allow to register custom `BroadcastReciver` while the app not running.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: I've now tried `WorkManager`, and it seems to be hugely unreliable in timing as well. Sorry about that.**

If you want to schedule a local notification that doesn't need extremely precise time, you're better off **not** using AlarmManager, as [many Android phones](https://dontkillmyapp.com/) will run it way too late, or never. Instead use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.google.cn/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) from androidx.

All this was explained awesomely by Josip Žitković in [this blog](https://martian.ventures/mantra/insights/schedule-local-notifications-on-android).

First, schedule the notification whereever you want:

```java
WorkRequest work = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
    .setInitialDelay(delay, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build()
;
WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(work);
```

Now create MyWorker, that will be called to show the actual notification:

```java
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;

public class MyWorker extends Worker {
    public MyWorker(
        @NonNull Context context,
        @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
    }

    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();

        // Intent to start when notification is tapped
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        createNotificationChannel(context);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "my_channel")
            .setContentTitle("hello, world")
            // Only on api < 26, see createNotificationChannel otherwise
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            // Default sound, vibration etc
            // Only on api < 26, see createNotificationChannel otherwise
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

        return Result.success();
    }

    /**
     * This needs to be called at least once on android API >= 26 before creating a notification.
     */
    public static void createNotificationChannel(Context context) {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("my_channel", "MyApp notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription("They will wake you up in the night");
            channel.enableVibration(true);

            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```