# Broadcastreceiver class in not updating intent value

Tags: android, android-intent

This is my first class MainActivity which is passing the value of mediaId through Intent.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(TimeActivity.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("MEDIAID", mediaId);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TimeActivity.this, 123, intent, 0);
```

This is my second class MyBroadcastReceiver which is getting the value of mediaId from MainActivity class.

```
    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
int mediaId = intent.getExtras().getInt("MEDIAID");
    }}
```

When I pass value of mediaId first time then it works properly but when I start application second time then it doesn't update value of mediaId in MyBroadcastReceiver class, It shows first value of mediaId.

My Question is:-
How to update the value of mediaId in MyBroadcastReceiver class ?

please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Use static to Store the value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getExtra from Intent launched from a pendingIntent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882459/getextra-from-intent-launched-from-a-pendingintent)

Answer (score 0):

Creating Pending Intent without the following flag with not update the intent data. It will show old data.

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,intentWithNewExtras,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```