# Is it possible to create multiple PendingIntents with the same requestCode and different extras?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm using `AlarmManager` to schedule anywhere between 1 and 35 alarms (depending on user input). When the user requests to schedule new alarms, I need to cancel the current alarms, so I create all of my alarms with the same requestCode, defined in a `final` variable.

```
// clear remaining alarms
Intent intentstop = new Intent(this, NDService.class);
PendingIntent senderstop = PendingIntent.getService(this,
            NODIR_REQUESTCODE, intentstop, 0);
am.cancel(senderstop);

// loop through days
if (sched_slider.getBooleanValue())
for (int day = 1; day < 8; day++) {

    if (day == 1 && sun.isChecked())
                scheduleDay(day);
    if (day == 2 && mon.isChecked())
                scheduleDay(day);
    if (day == 3 && tue.isChecked())
                scheduleDay(day);
    if (day == 4 && wed.isChecked())
                scheduleDay(day);
    if (day == 5 && thu.isChecked())
                scheduleDay(day);
    if (day == 6 && fri.isChecked())
                scheduleDay(day);
    if (day == 7 && sat.isChecked())
                scheduleDay(day);
}

...

public void scheduleDay(int dayofweek) {
    Intent toolintent = new Intent(this, NDService.class);
    toolintent.putExtra("TOOL", "this value changes occasionally");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this,
                NODIR_REQUESTCODE, toolintent, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayofweek);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pi);
}
```

Here, if the user has `sun` (which is a CheckBox) checked, it will schedule an alarm to run every Sunday at `hour` and `minute`. You can see that every alarm created this way has the same requestCode, but the `TOOL` extra changes sometimes for each alarm.

However, in my testing, when the alarm goes off and my Service runs, the extras from the Intent are now `null`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882459/getextra-from-intent-launched-from-a-pendingintent) suggests that using `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` will solve this, but wouldn't that cancel the other PendingIntents?

### In short:

Can someone explain how PendingIntents work, in reference to creating multiple ones with the same requestCode and different extras? What flags (if any) should I be using?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Actually, you don't "create" `PendingIntent`s. You request them from the Android framework. When you request a `PendingIntent` from the Android framework, it checks to see if there is already a `PendingIntent` that matches the criteria you pass as arguments. If so, it does not create a new `PendingIntent`, it just gives you back a "token" that points to the existing `PendingIntent`. If it doesn't find a matching `PendingIntent`, it will create one and then give you back a "token" that points to the one it just created. There are some flags that you can set to modify this behaviour, but not that much. The most important thing to understand here is the way the Android framework does the matching.

To do this it checks if the following parameters match (comparing the existing `PendingIntent` with the parameters you have passed):

- Request codes must be the same. Otherwise they do not match.
- The "action" in the `Intent` must be the same (or both null). Otherwise they do not match.
- The "data" in the `Intent` must be the same (or both null). Otherwise they do not match.
- The "type" (of the data) in the `Intent` must be the same (or both null). Otherwise they do not match.
- The "package" and/or "component" in the `Intent` must be the same (or both null). Otherwise they do not match. "package" and "component" fields are set for "explicit" `Intent`s.
- The list of "categories" in the `Intent` must be the same. Otherwise they do not match.

You should notice that "extras" **is not in the list above**. That means that if you request a `PendingIntent` the "extras" are not taken into consideration when the Android framework tries to find a matching `PendingIntent`. This is a common mistake that developers make.

We can now address the additional flags that you can add to modify the behaviour of a `PendingIntent` request:

`FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` - When you specify this flag, if a matching `PendingIntent` is found, that `PendingIntent` is cancelled (removed, deleted, invalidated) and a new one is created. This means that any applications that are holding a "token" pointing to the old `PendingIntent` will not be able to use it, because it is no longer valid.

`FLAG_NO_CREATE` - When you specify this flag, if a matching `PendingIntent` is found, a "token" pointing to the existing `PendingIntent` is returned (this is the usual behaviour). However, if no matching `PendingIntent` is found, a new one **is not created** and the call just returns `null`. This can be used to determine if there is an active `PendingIntent` for a specific set of parameters.

`FLAG_ONE_SHOT` - When you specify this flag, the `PendingIntent` that is created can only be used once. That means that if you give the "token" for this `PendingIntent` to multiple applications, after the first use of the `PendingIntent` it will be canceled (removed, deleted, invalidated) so that any future attempt to use it will fail.

`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` - When you specify this flag, if a matching `PendingIntent` is found, the "extras" in that `PendingIntent` will be replaced by the "extras" in the `Intent` that you pass as a parameter to the `getxxx()` method. If no matching `PendingIntent` is found, a new one is created (this is the normal behaviour). This can be used to change the "extras" on an existing `PendingIntent` where you have already given the "token" to other applications and don't want to invalidate the existing `PendingIntent`.

Let me try to address your specific problem:

You cannot have more than one active `PendingIntent` in the system if the request code, action, data, type and package/component parameters are the same. So your requirement to be able to have up to 35 active `PendingIntent`s all with the same request code, action, data, type and package/component parameters, but with different "extras", is not possible.

I would suggest that you either use 35 different request codes, or create 35 different unique "action" parameters for your `Intent`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! My Intents don't have data or actions, so you're saying I could potentially randomize one of those fields? And if I do this, I wouldn't really need to worry about the flags at all?

Comment: Oh I just thought of something as well.. If I randomized, say, the Action, then the "clear alarm" section of my code wouldn't work. I'd have to keep a record of the randomized Actions and set the Intents Action in a loop to clear all the alarms, correct?

Comment: Yes, you would. That's exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for this. The Android documentation is not that great regarding this...This is the only explanation that made sense for me.

Comment: I think you missed the Uri.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar No. The "Uri" is part of the **data** (which I mentioned). If you look at the `<intent-filter>` documentation, you will see a `<data>` specifier, not a `<uri>` specifier.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible just put **unique intent action** for each alarm

> intent.setAction("uniqueCode");

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReciver.class);
intent.setAction("uniqueCode");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0,   intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)       context.getSystemService(activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),   pendingIntent);
```