# NotificationCompat.Builder addAction - Boolean always true

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
public void sendNewNotification (Booking updateBooking) {

    String msg;
    if (updateBooking.getJobStatus () == Booking.eeJob_OnRoute) {
        msg = "Your driver has been dispatched.";
    } else if (updateBooking.getJobStatus () == Booking.eeJob_POB) {
        msg = "Your driver has arrived.";
    } else if (updateBooking.getJobStatus () == Booking.eeJob_Complete) {
        Variables.driverrated = false;
        msg = "Your booking has been completed. Thank you for using " + Variables.setting.getCompanysName () + ".";
    } else if (updateBooking.getJobStatus () == Booking.eeJob_NoShow) {
        msg = "Unfortunately your driver was unable locate you. Please call the office on " + Variables.setting.getCompanytelephone () + ".";
    } else if (updateBooking.getJobStatus () == Booking.eeJob_Cancelled) {
        msg = "Your booking has been cancelled. Please call the office on " + Variables.setting.getCompanytelephone () + " if this is incorrect.";
    } else {
        return;
    }

    PendingIntent detailsIntent =  PendingIntent.getActivity (this, 0, new Intent (this, HomeActivity.class)
            .putExtra ("booking", updateBooking)
            .putExtra ("track", false),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    PendingIntent trackingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity  (this, 0, new Intent (this, HomeActivity.class)
            .putExtra ("booking", updateBooking)
            .putExtra ("track", true),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder (this);
    builder.setAutoCancel (true);
    builder.setDefaults (Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    builder.setWhen (System.currentTimeMillis ());
    builder.setContentTitle (Variables.setting.getCompanysName () + " - booking update");
    builder.setSmallIcon (R.drawable.notification);
    builder.setTicker (Variables.setting.getCompanysName () + " - booking update");
    builder.setPriority (NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    builder.setContentText (msg);
    builder.setContentIntent (trackingIntent);

    builder.addAction (R.drawable.documents_32px, "DETAILS", detailsIntent);

    if (updateBooking.getJobStatus () != Booking.eeJob_Complete) {
        builder.addAction (R.drawable.notification, "TRACK", trackingIntent);
    } else {
        builder.addAction (R.drawable.profile_32px, "RATE", detailsIntent);
    }

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService (NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify (getTaskId (), builder.build ());

}
```

My issue is in my onCreate function I have these two lines:

```
m_updateBooking = (Booking) getIntent ().getSerializableExtra ("booking");
m_TrackDriver = (Boolean) getIntent ().getSerializableExtra ("track");
```

`m_updateBooking` works flawlessly. But `m_TrackDriver` is ALWAYS true. No matter what button I press. Can anyone explain why this is?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `Intent` has the same action for both the `PendingIntent`, you need to specify a different `requestCode` otherwise with `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` the *extras* in the `PendingIntent` will be replaced by the new *extras* in the `Intent`. For this reason you have always `true`, because it is in the last `PendingIntent` requested.

This [StackOveflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20205696/2837959) explains in details how `PendingIntent` works.

To resolve your issue change your code like this:

```
PendingIntent detailsIntent =  PendingIntent.getActivity (this, 0, new Intent (this, HomeActivity.class)
        .putExtra ("booking", updateBooking)
        .putExtra ("track", false),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

PendingIntent trackingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity  (this, 1, new Intent (this, HomeActivity.class)
        .putExtra ("booking", updateBooking)
        .putExtra ("track", true),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this information, much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel the answer solved the problem, please mark it as *accepted* by clicking the green check mark. Thanks.