# Not able to cancel Pending Intent using Alarm manager

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, notificationmanager

This is the code to set u and delete the notifications. please let me know if you need more details. The only solutions on stack overflow are about the pending intent to be same. I already tried that solution and it didn't work.

```
public void setAlarm () throws java.text.ParseException {
    RealmResults<Reminder> realmResults = getAllLatest();

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Reminder reminder =  getLatestReminder(realmResults);
    int hour = convertTimeToHoursAndMinutes(reminder.getReminderTime()).getHours();
    int minutes = convertTimeToHoursAndMinutes(reminder.getReminderTime()).getMinutes();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent  = getPendingIntentFromReminder(reminder);
    Log.v("Reminder is: ", String.valueOf(reminder));
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone());
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);


    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent);
}
private PendingIntent getPendingIntentFromReminder(Reminder reminder) throws ParseException {
    int hour = convertTimeToHoursAndMinutes(reminder.getReminderTime()).getHours();
    int minutes = convertTimeToHoursAndMinutes(reminder.getReminderTime()).getMinutes();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(reminder.getName());
    Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("TYS"),
            String.valueOf(reminder.getId()));
    intent.setData(data);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone());
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    //Log.v("Test", calendar.getTimeZone().toString());
    // Log.v("Hours to show", String.valueOf(hour));
    // Log.v("Minutes to show", String.valueOf(minutes));
    intent.putExtra("reminderTitle", reminder.getName());
    //  Log.v("Reminder Name", reminder.getName());
    intent.putExtra("notificationType", 1);
    intent.putExtra("reminderId", String.valueOf(reminder.getId()));
    intent.putExtra("reminderSubtitle", reminder.getSubTitle());
    intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    Log.v("set Alarm", String.valueOf(intent));
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    return alarmIntent;
}

public void deleteReminderIntent(Reminder reminder) throws ParseException {
    Log.v("deleteReminderIntent", String.valueOf(reminder));
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =getPendingIntentFromReminder(reminder);
    alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
    pendingIntent.cancel();
    //alarmMgr.cancel(temp);
   // alarmMgr.cancel(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getPendingIntentFromReminder()` you set the **ACTION** in the `Intent` to the current time. When you call the method to get a `PendingIntent` to cancel your alarm, the current time is different, so the **ACTION** will not match the `PendingIntent` you have used to set the alarm.

In order to cancel the alarm, you need to use an `Intent` that will match the `Intent` that you used to set the alarm. The following parameters in the `Intent` must match:

- ACTION
- CATEGORY
- DATA
- COMPONENT

Any "extras" in the `Intent` are ignored, so they do not need to match.

For more details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29590084/769265 and
[Is it possible to create multiple PendingIntents with the same requestCode and different extras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204284/is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-pendingintents-with-the-same-requestcode-and-d/20205696#20205696)