# Show multiple daily repeating notifications in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alarmmanager

In my app I want to show as many daily notifications as user wants (it's sort of a medical reminder). User also sets time of the new notification. But my app currently shows only one, latest notification. Could you help me solve this problem?

My code for creating new notification (`setHour` etc. are previously set by the user):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, setHour);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, setMinute);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(ReminderActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ReminderActivity.this, MID,intent1, 0);
                    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ReminderActivity.this.getSystemService(ReminderActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

And my `AlarmReceiver`:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static int MID = 0;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "this.is.my.channelId";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(MID, 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

        Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("New Notification")
                .setTicker("New Message Alert!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
//below creating notification channel, because of androids latest update, O is Oreo
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "NotificationDemo",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(MID, notification);
        MID++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a `PendingIntent` here

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ReminderActivity.this, MID,intent1, 0);
```

please check that you aren't passing the same request code `MID`. In this case Android "reuses" the pending intent which were created previously, that's why you would see only the latest notification instead of several notifications.

It seems the easiest way to avoid the issue would be passing different request codes (or another params, for example different `setAction(...)` - see the link below) for every type of notifications.

For more info please have a look at how Android compares pending intents: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20205696/2219237