# Getting all pending intents

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I am creating notification with button:

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(MyApp.appContext, FCM_CHANNEL)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noticon)
                    .setLargeIcon(image)
                    .setContentTitle(user?.name)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
```

And adding pendingIntent:

```
val responseIntent = Intent(MyApp.appContext, ResponseBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
responseIntent.putExtra(ResponseBroadcastReceiver.USER_ID, fromUid)

  val flags: Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                        else
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                        
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyApp.appContext, abs(fromUid.hashCode()), responseIntent, flags)

builder.addAction(0, "Reply", pendingIntent)
builder.setContentText("Please respond")
```

I have couple of questions:

1. Because for each notification I create new pendingIntent how can I list all of them to see which active? As I understand I am limited to 35 (what happens after 35?) https://stackoverflow.com/a/20205696
2. Does adding "setAutoCancel(true)" to NotificationCompat.Builder removes the pendingIntent when notification dismissed (that is what I want)
3. I wish that bending intent only be triggered once (PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT) and Mutable, is this the correct approach for handling different SDK versions?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/security/risks/pending-intent

Answer (score -2):

1. Listing all active `PendingIntents`:
   Android does not provide a native way to list all active `PendingIntents`. The reason is that the `PendingIntent` is a token that the application gives to another application (e.g., Notification Manager), and the other application uses that token to perform an operation on behalf of the application that owns the `PendingIntent`. The `PendingIntent` is not tracked by the system, so there is no central registry to query for active `PendingIntents`. However, you can manage the active `PendingIntents` within your app manually. For example, you can store them in a data structure like a list or a map when you create them and remove them when they are used or no longer needed.
2. `setAutoCancel(true)` and `PendingIntent`:
   The `setAutoCancel(true)` method in `NotificationCompat.Builder` will only dismiss the notification when the user clicks on it. It does not explicitly remove or cancel the `PendingIntent` associated with the notification or its actions. However, since you're using `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`, the `PendingIntent` can only be used once. After it has been used, it will be automatically canceled by the system and cannot be used again.
3. `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` and `Mutable` `PendingIntent`:
   Your approach to handling different SDK versions is correct. Using `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` ensures that the `PendingIntent` can only be used once. For SDK versions S (Android 12) and above, you are also using `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE`, which means that the PendingIntent's extras can be updated. For SDK versions below S, you're using `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, which allows updating the `PendingIntent` if it already exists.

In summary, your approach for handling different SDK versions and making the `PendingIntent` one-shot and mutable is correct. Just remember that you'll need to manage the active `PendingIntents` within your app if you need to keep track of them.