# Activity not refreshed when click on push notification from notification tray if same activity is opened

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification

Scenario: I have two notifications on notification tray, when my app is opened and i clicked on first notification then its open in notification activity and is working correctly but i removed app from background and then i will click on any notification and its first time load correctly that notification but when i click second time it will not update the activity, it always show that activity and onResume() of that activity is not called so i am not able to update data in activity because i click on second notification that contain different text string.
Any help will be appropriated

Comment: You need to force the Activity to use your new Intent's data or else it won't refresh. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23202708/1426565

Comment: Thanks for you answer but actually i tried this with onNewIntent(), but when i clicked on notification this method is not called basically no method is called of that notification activity if that activity is on top of stack. Please help